# Can I go back to complete quests in Costume Quest?

Tags: costume-quest

I'm playing Costume Quest, and I'm up to the Mall.  I just looked at my quest log and realised that I missed one of the hide-and-seekers in Suburbia.  Gah.

Will there be any opportunity to revisit the area and obtain missed quests?  Or would I have to start a new save to do so?

(Note: I'm playing this on PC, I don't think it's relevant but I thought I'd point it out.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will be able to go back - at the end of each area there is a teleport coffin that will allow you to go back to areas you have already been to.